# Vuejs intercomponent data exchange

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs3

I'am looking for a library/hook which I can use for loose-coupled data-exchange between related component. I could imagine something like this:

const { data, setData } = useStore('any.store-identifier')

I would expect data to be a ref which is updated if any component uses set setData function to update the structure. It is important that I do not have to predefine the stores. Any component which uses the same identifier will act on the same store which is created on first reference.

This is somehow a mix between vue-query and useState. Does anyone know if something like this is around or an other/better way to achieve this behavior? Of course I was googling before but I did really find something. Thank you for any hint!

Best regards,
Dominic

Comment: Hi Dominic what about vuex ? https://v3.vuex.vuejs.org/

Comment: Hi Sayf, I use vuex for related things. I think in vuex you have to predefine the datastructure and this is what I don't want to do. An other thing is that in vuex you have to use the getters und mutations and so on for manipulation. That's quite heavy - I am looking for something light weight. Thanky you very much for your advice!

Comment: So if you want a lighter and softer state manager i will advice you to use `Pinia` then maybe it's the best option for you it does not have `mutations`, as any change to state now registers an implicit mutation, regardless of where it's performed


https://pinia.vuejs.org/introduction.html

Comment: Otherwise i can advise you to play with the reactive api and do your custom store the if you don't want to use any of these and then create your datastructure 

https://vuejs.org/guide/scaling-up/state-management.html

Comment: Hi Sayf, I just experimented a little bit with your last suggestion sharing reactive between components. I think that could do the job for me. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hi for anyone who would do as Dominic and do not want to:

- Have to predefine the data structure
- Use specific method declared by any plugin or dependency
- Be dependent of some structure or code base

You can use directly: [Vue State Management Sharing reactive](https://vuejs.org/guide/scaling-up/state-management.html)

And create your own state management system

Hope it will help other persons